# How to render style according to the url parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to replace css file according to url parameter, `site` and `site/index/en` need to get different style.

so how can i do something like this:

```
 @section css {
        @Styles.Render(@RouteData.Values["id"] == "en" ? "~/Content/holdings/en" : "~/Content/holdings" )
}
```

Comment: So does this code work? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is pretty close, I think you're just missing the ViewContext;

```
@section css {
    @Styles.Render(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() == "en" ? "~/Content/holdings/en" : "~/Content/holdings" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar case where i had to switch between languages and i used cookies to store the users chosen language

so you could use something similar to this

```
@{
   var lang = "~/Content/holdings/";
   lang += Request.Cookies["key"].Value; //they key will hold they lang Code in this case en
   @Styles.Render(lang)
}
```

keep in mind if you dont want to use a cookie you can use a session as well

if you have many different CSS file then store the filepaths in an array and then looping the arraylist adding en to the string.

I hope this answer helps you out.

PS I would recommend a class that is specifically built for this validating the incoming parameter from the URL if you wish to continue and implement a fallback language in case something goes wrong so that the page will also render correctly.